# How to go back to the last commit in the history after I used git reset to go to an older changeset?

Tags: git, git-reset

Suppose my history goes that way :

A - B - C - D (master)

If I do `git reset B`, I'll got :

A - B (master)

Trouble is, `git log` now show me only the history from A to B, and I can't see C and D anymore.

How can I go back to D ?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You should be able to see D with [`git reflog`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reflog.html).

See this [article for instance](http://gitfu.wordpress.com/2008/04/06/git-reflog-no-commits-left-behind/).

> The only time commits are actually deleted is if you git gc --prune (so be careful with that one!).
>
> If you run git reflog right now in a repository you’ve been working in, you’ll see lots of changes that look something like this:

```
c5c3a82... HEAD@{0}: pull origin featureB: Merge made by recursive.
49d0608... HEAD@{1}: reset --hard HEAD^: updating HEAD
3ed01b1... HEAD@{2}: pull origin featureA: Merge made by recursive.
49d0608... HEAD@{3}: pull origin bugfixJ: Merge made by recursive.
854d44e... HEAD@{4}: commit: Add more cowbell to foo.c
6dbc22d... HEAD@{5}: pull origin bugfixI: Merge made by recursive.
9bdb763... HEAD@{6}: commit: Remove weevils
8518f9d... HEAD@{7}: checkout: moving from wickedfeature to master
```

> These lines can be broken down into 4 parts:
>
> - commit hash,
> - commit pointer,
> - action,
> - and extra info.
>
> If we wanted to get back the commit that was lost at `HEAD@{1}`, we could just `git reset --hard HEAD@{2}`.
>   Now our current branch (and working copy) are set to the repository state before we did the reset.
>
> If we wanted to just see what that state was, we could `git checkout -b temp HEAD@{2}` (or `git checkout HEAD@{2}` if you have git 1.5.0 and up).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found it.

You can use `git reflog`.

I didn't know what it was for, but now I can see it's a log of all the references HEAD have been pointing to.